# Android ConstraintLayout backward compatible to older android version?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I am using Android Studio 3.5 and developing new Android App which must run on Android 4.0 and later.

I want to use ConstraintLayout. Will my app be compatible with Android 4.0?

Comment: yes it will work on it also on 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minsdk **depends** by the library used:

With the **support library**  (the class is `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`) you can use:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3' --> minSdk=9
```

With **androidx** (the class is `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`) you can use:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2" --> minSdk=14
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"  --> minSdk=9
```

Comment: When I create a new project in Android Studio 3.5, I have to specify minimum API level. If I choose API level 14 (Android 4.0) which is the lowest API it can go, will I be able to use ConstraiintLayout ? The reason I was confused is that ContraintLaoyout started in Android 7.0.

Comment: @ace Yes the ConstraintLayout works with this level. Also check the [android distribution](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) because today with api=21 you can cover over the 90%.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It will work on 4.0, It has **backward compatible till api level 9** , Please check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) for more information.